# C++ Pointers to functions

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}

int subtraction (int a, int b)
{
    return (a-b);
}
int operation (int x, int y, int (*functocall)(int,int))
{
    int g;
    g = (*functocall)(x,y);
    return(g);
}
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;

    m = operation (7,5,addition);
    n = operation (20,m,minus);
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain this line for me

```
int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"minus" is a name of a variable which is a pointer to a function taking two int arguments and returning another int. 
The function called "operation" takes 3 arguments: 2 ints and a pointer to a function which operates on 2 ints and return another one.  When invoked, the operation function applies argument 3 to the arguments 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Happy new year.

Answer (score 3):

**int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;** is creating a variable called **minus** and assigning it a pointer to the function called **subtraction**.  if the code is valid then the function **subtraction** would be declared **int subtraction(int a, int b);**.

the best way to deal with function pointers is to make them readable using typedef.

example:

```
typedef int (*math_op)(int,int); // new types is math_op

int subtraction (int a, int b)
{
    return (a-b);
}

math_op minus = subtraction;
```

later on these can be called like they are normal functions.

example:

```
int result = minus(10, 2); // result is now set to 8
```

your code rewritten:

```
using namespace std;

typedef int (*math_op)(int,int); // new types is math_op

int addition (int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}

int subtraction (int a, int b)
{
    return (a-b);
}

int operation (int x, int y, math_op functocall)
{
    int g;
    g = functocall(x,y);
    return(g);
}

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    math_op minus = subtraction;

    m = operation (7,5,addition);
    n = operation (20,m,minus);
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*minus)(int,int)
```

says

> A pointer to a function taking two ints as arguments returning an int.

The parentheses around `(*minus)` are there to make sure that the asterisk binds to the name of the typedef and not the return type (i.e., the function does not return an int*).